# Updating a table in JSP with Struts 2 without reloading the page

Tags: ajax, jsp, struts2

I have a board game with a table.

This table comes from the struts Action (look the red rectangle) :

[Struts Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNvCk.jpg)

```
public NewCase [][] getPlateauJoueurCourant() {
    return maFacade.getPlateau(getIdentifiant()).getMonPlateau();
}
```

And then in the JSP Struts, I use iterator to show the table :

[JSP Struts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBUNT.jpg)

```
<table border="">
    <s:iterator value="plateauJoueurCourant" var="ligne" status="posX">
    <br>
        <s:iterator value="ligne" var="lacase"  status="posY">
            <s:set var="myVar" value="valeur" />
            <img src="img\box0.png" height="50" width="50" 
    class="<s:property value="#posX.index" /><s:property value="#posY.index" />">
        </s:iterator>
    </s:iterator>
</table>
```

It's a board game, 2 players are on the board.

Now let's say I'm player 1. I will move a piece. Now I would like the player 2 to have the table updated so he can see I moved the piece.

I was thinking about Ajax with JQuery. But I don't know how to handle it. In the success function of the ajax request, I can't handle a JAVA object of type NewCase[][]. So I was thinking about converting my java object in json and then use JQuery to show the json so I got the table updated.

Do you have any ideas ? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: The question is too broad. Yes, you can and should use AJAX, yes, jQuery is ok for that, yes, you send data from the AJAX action in JSON form (json result and root object) and retrieve it in the success callback of your jQuery $.get function, and then iterate it and use the values of the matrix to redraw your HTML components by retrieving them by ID or whatever and then setting their val() or html() always with jQuery. Start step by step, with a single value, then an array, then with your matrix, and you'll be good. This is the best you can get as an answer here I guess... good luck BTW

Comment: You can use struts 2 jquery plugin, which make it easier for you if you are not familiar with AJAX, see the sample at http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action. As you can see lots of page content are updated without page reloading.